# How to get longitude and latitude from map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dictionary, html-parsing

I have alreddy tried at my best but still unabble to find out longitude and latitude of all marker peresented in map....

```
 Link: www.eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/default.aspx
 Rajasthan -> ajmer -> Ajmer north -> press clickhere ..
```

I anyone of you know please tell me **how to find all these marker's longitude and latitude** that appeared in this link map...

My need is i want to save all marker's  longitude and latitude in my database....

any tyype of help apprecited

Comment: I know all marker is presented in jaavascript...but don't know how to find out...

Comment: Thanks @user3124973 for comment..but i know it's present ..but don't know how to extract them...

Comment: the marker-data will be loaded via a AJAX-request to http://www.eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/GService.asmx/GetGoogleObject . When you are the site-owner you should know how to access these data. When not, you should ask the site-owner 1. for permission 2. if there is a service available to access these data

Comment: @Dr.Molle sir i am not owner of this site..according to you i think i couldn't do this??

Comment: I didn't say that you couldn't do it, but if you wan't to use external data you should ask the owner for permission(except there are license-informations available that give you permission to use these data). There are many kindly people in the world, just ask them.

Comment: ok thanku @Dr.Molle ,I got it.. i will ask for permission........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the marker-data will be loaded via a AJAX-request to
eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/GService.asmx/GetGoogleObject .

Site-owner should know how to access these data. When not, you should ask the site-owner

1. for permission
2. if there is a service available to access these data –
   Answeres by Dr. Molle..